# CSS print stylesheet generated content not showing up

Tags: html, css, printing, css-gcpm

I've been having a weird problem where content generated through CSS for print stylesheets won't show up. The print stylesheet is applied on print, but the generated content just doesn't show up.

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testprint</title>
<style>

    @media print {
        @page {
            size: auto;
            margin: 2cm;
            @top-center { 
                content: 'dsdsdfsdfdfs';
                font-size: 10pt;
                text-align: center;
                color: black;
            }
        }
        h1 {
            color: red;
        }
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PRINT</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The red coloring of the h1 is applied on print, but the content from the @top-center selector doesn't show up. Would greatly appreaciate any pointers on how to resolve this.

Comment: `content` relates to pseudo-elements..and I don't see one.

Comment: @Paulie_D are you sure that applies to print stylesheets as well? I've seen this code used in tutorials, for instance https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Comment: Interesting...do you have a demo?

Comment: @Paulie_D Just copy the code from above and put it in a testprint.html file or similar, open it in a browser and that should work as a demo!

Comment: @Paulie_D: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/ I'm not actually sure if it's implemented in any mainstream browser.

Comment: @BoltClock You appear to be right, should have been more careful checking if it was supported. If you write that in an answer I'll select it as the right one. It's too bad, would have been very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature of the [CSS Generated Content for Paged Media](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3) (affectionately known as GCPM) module. There are no known stable implementations of GCPM in mainstream browsers at this time, though there is some coverage of the related [CSS Paged Media 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page) module.